# how to check whether checkbox is checked in datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a Datagridview within a windows form which loads data. I have also included a checkbox column to this Datagridview in run time. My question is how can i know if any of the checkboxs from the checkbox column has been checked, and if a checkbox has been checked enable a button. I have used CellValueChanged event to perform above task but unable to get the desired result.

This is what i have done

```
 List<int> ChkedRow = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= Datagridview1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells["chkcol"].Value) == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
button1.Enabled = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Datagridview1.Rows)
{
    if (((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["chkcol"]).Value)
      {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        break;
      }

}
```

or

```
//This will always call the checking of checkbox whenever you ticked the checkbox in the datagrid
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == [Your column index])
       CheckForCheckedValue();
}

private void CheckForCheckedValue()
{
   button1.Enabled = false;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Datagridview1.Rows)
   {
    if (((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["chkcol"]).Value)
      {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

**NOTE**
Don't forget to check the for Null value and do something if it is NULL

Comment: Above code worked but when i uncheck all checkbox, button is not disabled. even added button1.Enabled = false in else part.

Comment: You should add Call this function inside the CellValueChanged of the datagridview and check if the cell for the check box is the one that changed value and then execute the code

Answer (score 1):

set `false` before the loop

```
button1.Enabled = false;
```

when you found checked item, set it as Enabled `true` and `break` the loop

```
button1.Enabled = true;
break;
```

code:

```
button1.Enabled = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= Datagridview1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells["chkcol"].Value))
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can do below as well

```
button1.Enabled = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[colCheckIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
   if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue){
      button1.Enabled = true;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that i want to check whether any one checkbox has been checked. i.e. user checked any checkbox in a column, button should be enabled and if no checkbox has been checked than button should be disabled.